# Commutative diagram in below photo

Tags: beamer

I want write the commutative digram in LaTex and Beamer? But I can't, could you help me?

[image: Commutative digarm]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will feel much more satisfied if you try yourself. There is nothing in this which is tricky (with the possible exception that you need `fragile`). (Unfortunately `tikz-cd` can not be hacked easily in the same way as a matrix of nodes, which would have allowed us to avoid a lot of repetition but copy and paste is also fast.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
\frametitle{Diagram}
\begin{tikzcd}
 & \arrow[d,"d^H"] & \arrow[d,"d^H"] & \arrow[d,"d^H"] \\
 0 \arrow[r] & \mathcal{I}^{ev} \arrow[r] \arrow[d,"d^H"]& 
 \Omega^{ev}(M) \arrow[r] \arrow[d,"d^H"] & 
 \Omega^{ev}(M)/\mathcal{I}^{ev} \arrow[r]  \arrow[d,"d^H"]& 0\\
 0 \arrow[r] & \mathcal{I}^{od} \arrow[r] \arrow[d,"d^H"]& 
 \Omega^{od}(M) \arrow[r] \arrow[d,"d^H"]& 
 \Omega^{od}(M)/\mathcal{I}^{od} \arrow[r]  \arrow[d,"d^H"]& 0\\
  & ~ & ~ & ~ & \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]